# Multiple js progressbars on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, oop, progress-bar

I'm working on a project with progressbar.js and I want to have multiple progress bars on my page. There is a dynamic amount so I'm not sure ahead of time how much progressbars I will have on the page.

I my JSFiddle I have simply duplicated the code and gave the second progressbar a **.progress2** class. Ideally I would want to have the progressbar working for each element by simply giving it a **.progress** class

http://jsfiddle.net/8xa87k31/497/

```
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('.progress', {
    color: startColor,
    easing: 'linear',
    strokeWidth: 8,
    duration: 1500,
    text: {
        value: '0'
    }
});
```

Obviously I guess I would start by gathering the values and putting those into an array but I can't even get that working. Could somebody give me a push in the right direction since I'm not that good with javascript.

I would be really grateful if somebody would take a look and tell me if this can even be done the way I would want it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Evening Stephan,

I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/8xa87k31/499/

```
$('.progress').each(function() {
    var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle(this, {
        color: startColor,
        easing: 'linear',
        strokeWidth: 8,
        duration: 1500,
        text: {
            value: '0'
        }
    });

    var value = ($(this).attr('value') / 100);

    circle.animate(value, {
        from: {
            color: startColor
        },
        to: {
            color: endColor
        },
        step: function(state, circle, bar) {
            circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
            console.log(circle);
            circle.setText((circle.value() * 100).toFixed(0));
        }
    });
});
```

See? No big deal! :-)

NB: I'm convinced, this could be improved.

Comment: You are my hero :) so simple, yet so effective.

Comment: You're welcome, you won't get stuck next time that's all that matters! :)